# HTML validation error: Stray end tag head

Tags: php, html, w3c-validation

I am trying to validating my website on validator.w3.org. And I have resolved so many errors, but some errors I am not able to resolve. So please help me to resolve this one. Here is my code :

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<!--<title>
<?php //echo wp_title('|',true,'right'); ?>
</title>-->
<?php
$layout = vibe_get_option('layout');
if(!isset($layout) || !$layout)
$layout = '';
wp_head();
?>
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://digital-marketing-courses.com/wp-content/themes/wplms/assets/images/icooon.png" property="uploads">
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-74076097-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
</head>
<body <?php body_class($layout); ?>>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the validator, but i guess you're not supposed to validate php and javascript with it. Try validating only static content.

Answer (score 0):

https://validator.w3.org/ and https://validator.w3.org/nu/ (to which the first one redirects if HTML5 gets checked) check HTML documents, not PHP documents.

So first run your PHP program, then check the HTML it generates.